# Mulitiline Variable in jinja2

Tags: variables, jinja2, whitespace, multiline

i'm trying to read/store a multiline variable in jinja2. However, it's not well parsed and i' getting many breakline and space between the character. Would be nice if ca receive a hint how to solve it.
The code look like this:

```
>    certificate: |-
>{% for line in certificate %}
>          {{ line }}
>{% endfor %}
>
>{% if destinationCACertificate is defined %}
>        destinationCACertificate: |-
>{% for line in destinationCACertificate %}
>          {{ line }}
>{% endfor %}
>{% endif %}
```

I want to get something like this:

```
certificate: |-
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      MIIM1TCCCr2gAwIBAgITGAAAH6w6I7/Kn4g5bwAAAAAfrDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
      ADBtMQswCQYDVQQGEwJERTEaMBgGA1UEBwwRRnJhbmtmdXJ0IGFtIE1haW4xFzAV
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is considered here as a character. The split function should be added telling jinja to to consider a line still it find a breakline ('\n').

So it should be something like:

> 

```
 certificate: |-
    >    {% for line in certificate.split('\n') %}
    >    {{ line }}
    >    {% endfor %}
    >    {% endif %}
    >    {% if destinationCACertificate is defined %}
    >    destinationCACertificate: |-
    >    {% for line in destinationCACertificate.split('\n') %}
    >    {{ line }}
    >    {% endfor %}
    >    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this here for anyone who might be interested in how you can set multiline variables in Javascript for example;

```
var myData = `{{ multiline_string }}`
```

as the backtick (`) character starts and ends a multiline string. This worked for my use case at least